# Why System.getProperties() returns null for -D defined property?

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

I'm running a jarball using

```
java -classpath myBatch.jar some.package.MyMainClass \
     -bloodyArgument "I got the argument!" -Dbloody.prop="I got the prop!"
```

Then in my main I have:

```
Properties argsProps = BatchUtils.argsToProperties(args);
System.out.println(argsProps.getProperty("bloodyArgument"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("bloody.prop"));
```

And I get output:

```
I got the argument!
null
```

I can see the command line bloodyArgument (I added it to see if "something" gets passed to the program), but I'd expect the **-D** argument to set the system property. Why is the "bloody.prop" null?

PS: BatchUtils.argsToProperties() does what you'd expected it to do: parse *-argName "value"* from command line into *argName=value* property pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything **after the class** argument of java command gets **passed to your main in String[] args** and doesn't make it to the JVM.

The solution was to rearrange the properties like this:

```
java -classpath myBatch.jar -Dbloody.prop="I got the prop!" \
     some.package.MyMainClass -bloodyArgument "I got the argument!"
```

---

I didn't find this anywhere explicitly stated when waddling the web with http://duckduckgo.com or googling this queation of *"null -D defined property"*. I figured it a lot later when printing all system properties and the whole arguments array, so am posting for others.

Comment: You didn't find [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)?! It's quite clear: *"Arguments after the class file name or the JAR file name are passed to the main() method."*

Comment: @T.J. Yes, now that I know what the problem was it's cristal clear. It's easy, when you look for "java cmd line arguments" or something. But did you try to find the documentation, when searching specifically for my problem e.g.: "got null for -D defined system property"? There is no link I came across and at the end I had to figure it out by hand, what took me a lot of time.